# Catch PHP exception

Tags: php, try-catch

I'm using the UrbanAirship library and importing it into my php script and then using it like so:

```php
use UrbanAirship\Push as P;

// Down inside some method...
try {
    $dev = P\deviceToken('....');
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    continue;
}
```

If I look at the deviceToken method I see them throwing the InvalidArgumentException on bad input.  However, when this happens, my script just aborts with the exception, instead of catching it and moving on.

Is there something special I have to do to catch this exception?

Comment: What exception does it throw ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling that namespaces might be complicating your issue.

> When catching an exception inside a namespace it is important that you escape to the global space.

Try this:

```
use UrbanAirship\Push as P;

// Down inside some method...
try {
    $dev = P\deviceToken('....');
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue!  Adding the \ in front of the exception name made it work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
continue;
```

only works in loops.  If you don't want to do anything with the exception, simply leave the catch block empty.

```
use UrbanAirship\Push as P;

// Down inside some method...
try {
    $dev = P\deviceToken('....');
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: I am in a loop.  I was just showing a snipped.  Even if that weren't the case though, your suggestion didn't address the issue that the exception was not being caught.